# Right to seek alms and live

Tags: practice

We learnt that Brahmins have right to seek alms and live with it. Can people from other castes live through begging as per scriptures?

Comment: in grahshth ashram or sanyas ashram?

Comment: Practice is Sanyasa ashram.